# How to access variables other than @Input params on ngOnChanges in Angular?

Tags: angular, ngonchanges

I encountered a scenario where i need to do some processing of data on ngOnchanges(as the data is coming through @Input data bound property from parent component). During this transformation i need to use a property initialized in ngOnInit. I tried to use it directly but the value is coming as undefined. Can someone let me know how can i achieve this.  Below is an example code for my scenario.

```
ParentComp HTML
<myParent [data]="list$ | async"></myParent>

ChildComp TS
export class {
  @Input() data : any ; //data from parent
  breakPoint$: Observable<number>

  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(){
   this.breakPoint$ = fromEvent(this.window, 'resize').pipe(
      map(() => this.numOfCols())
    );
  }

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['data']) {
       // need to do some data processing here based on numOfColumns value, so trying to access
       this.breakPoint$.pipe(

       ) // Here i get cannot read property pipe of undefined error
      );

 numOfCols(): number {
    return this.breakpointObserver.isMatched(`(max-width: 1008px)`) ? 4 : 5;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another input propery and move numOfCols$ into the parent component.

ParentComp HTML

```
<myParent [data]="list$ | async"
          [numOfCols]="numOfCols$ | async>
</myParent>
```

ParentCom TS

```
numOfCols$: Observable<number>;

constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
   this.numOfCols$ = breakpointObserver.observe('(max-width: 1008px)').pipe(
      map(({matches}) => matches ? 4 : 5)
   );
}
```

ChildComp TS

```
@Input() data: any;
@Input() numOfCols: number;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['data']) {
        // You can use this.numOfCols here
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, using a "breakpoint service" would be a lot nicer ! Good idea !

Comment: @Nifiro and Random , thank you. I was thinking about doing this, but my bad i missed to check the order of lifecycle hooks triggered and came up with question.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the usage of [`withLatestFrom`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom) rxjs operator here. I will create an Observable for `numOfColumns`, whenever this gets updated
the final subscription would trigger. BUT: it would not trigger until, you have the data from `ngOnInit()` (second Observable), and will only trigger
if `numOfColumns` is updated after that, i.e. Subsequent changes of `BreakPoint` won't trigger the subscription, If you want it to be triggered on both then you can use [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip) instead.

I am doing this in a `setter`, you can use `ngOnChanges` as well

```
_numOfColumns;
numOfColumnsObs$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

set numOfColumns(val) {
    this._numOfColumns = val;
    this.numOfColumnsObs$.next(val);
}

get numOfColumns() {
    return this._numOfColumns
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.breakPoint$ = fromEvent(this.window, 'resize').pipe(
        map(() => this.numOfCols())
        );

        // new code here.
        this.numOfColumnsObs$.pipe(withLatestFrom(this.breakPoint$))
        .pipe(filter(([columns]) => columns !== false))
        .subscribe(([columns, breakPoint]) => {
            // do the changes you wanted in `ngOnChanges`;
        })
}
```

You would need a BehaviorSubject here, because the observable would be emitted before subscription. Since there is a BehaviorSubject, there is a hack, I have initialized it with `false`. Assuming that numOfColumns would never come as `false`. If it would, you can initialize it with any value which is not possible to come and filter it later by piping it.

Comment: Why not using a BehaviorSubject for this behavior ?

Comment: @Random: Yeah, you are right, it won't work without a BehaviorSubject, let me update.

Comment: @Asish thanks a lot. Thta's a great explanation. It's a good learning for me. I will try this solution too.

Answer (score 0):

ngOnChanges is first triggered before ngOnInit. Because Inputs are filled before ngOnInit.
If you need values comming from ngOnInit, you may use a boolean "isInitDone" inside the ngOnChanges. And don't forget to set this boolean to true inside your ngOnInit.

But then, you should also trigger what is done in the ngOnChanges method. so maybe putting it inside amethod, where both ngOnChanges and ngOnInit would call...

An other solution would be to move ngOnInit code to ngOnChanges, inside an `if (this.breakpoint$)`

Answer (score 0):

Angular's component lifecycle hooks are triggered in the following order:

1. ngOnChanges
2. ngOnInit
3. ngDoCheck
4. ngAfterContentInit
5. ngAfterContentChecked
6. ngAfterViewInit
7. ngAfterViewChecked
8. ngOnDestroy

As you can see, you're trying to access a property that's not defined the in the first ngOnChanges. You could simple add a check in your if statement like this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['data'] && !!this.breakPoint$) {
....
```

or you could even define breakPoint$ outside of ngOnInit, like this:

```
   @Input() data : any ; //data from parent
   breakPoint$: Observable<number> = fromEvent(this.window, 'resize').pipe(
      map(() => this.numOfCols())
    );
```